# возможно ли из a получить b

Tags: python, теория-чисел

всем привет, есть два числа, нужно проверить возможно ли получить из числа a другое число b, умножая его на число которое делится на a и посчитать кол-во шагов за которое это можно сделать, например:

```
a = 2
b = 16
```

результат такой: 2 --> 4 --> --> 8 -- > 16 ( за 3 шага)
в голове нет идей, как это реализовать, пытался через делители числа, но получилось решить только частично. нужна идея для эффективного решения, т.к лимит времени 1.0 сек и ограничение памяти 64мб.

условие задачи тут:

> Студенту снится сон. Во сне он ходит по городу, в котором ужасно много
> трактиров. В каждом трактире выпивает кружку эля. Все трактиры
> пронумерованы целыми положительными числами, и из трактира с номером n
> можно пойти только в трактир с номером, который делится на n.
> Начинается сон в трактире с номером a. Студент знает, что ему надо
> попасть в трактир с номером b. При этом, понятно, хочет по пути выпить
> как можно больше эля. Если он не может дойти из трактира a в трактир
> b, то сразу просыпается в холодном поту.

Comment: Разложить на простые множители...

Comment: Проверить что *b* делится на  *a*. Если да, то разложить на простые *a / b*. Число шагов - сумма степеней простых в разложении.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy
спасибо большое, а можно поподробнее почему это так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если *b* не делится на *a*, то добраться из *a* в *b* студент не может.

Пусть *b* делится на *a*.

Разложим на простые *a = p<sub>1</sub><sup>u<sub>1</sub></sup> p<sub>2</sub><sup>u<sub>2</sub></sup> ...*, *b = p<sub>1</sub><sup>v<sub>1</sub></sup> p<sub>2</sub><sup>v<sub>2</sub></sup> ...*, где p<sub>i</sub> - все простые числа.

*b* делится на *a*, значит *∀ i, u<sub>i</sub> ≤ v<sub>i</sub>*.

Если *с* между *a* и *b*, то *a < c < b*, *a* делит *c*, *с* делит *b*. Разложим на простые *c = p<sub>1</sub><sup>w<sub>1</sub></sup> p<sub>2</sub><sup>w<sub>2</sub></sup> ...*

*∀ i, u<sub>i</sub> ≤ w<sub>i</sub> ≤ v<sub>i</sub>*

Вместо того чтобы рассматривать делители, будет рассматривать вектора *(w<sub>i</sub>)*. Начинается цепочка векторов в *(u<sub>i</sub>)*, заканчивается в *(v<sub>i</sub>)*. Каждый шаг увеличивает один или несколько элементов *w* на единицу или больше. Минимальный шаг увеличивает один элемент на единицу. Всего можно сделать шагов ∑<sub>i</sub>(v<sub>i</sub> - u<sub>i</sub>).

Утверждение: число шагов из *a* в *b* равно числу шагов из *1* в *n (= b / a)*. Доказательство - почти очевидно.

Программа ниже разлагает *n* на простые множители и конструирует из них маршрут студента. Сложность *O(√(b/a))*:

```
import math


def factors(n):
    i = 2
    j = n
    j_sqrt = math.isqrt(j)
    while i <= j_sqrt:
        if j % i == 0:
            while j % i == 0:
                j //= i
                yield i
            j_sqrt = math.isqrt(j)
        i += 1 if i == 2 else 2
    if j > 1:
        yield j


def steps(a, b):
    p, q = divmod(b, a)
    if q == 0:
        c = a
        yield c
        for f in factors(p):
            c *= f
            yield c



def main():
    s = tuple(steps(*map(int, input().split())))
    print(len(s) - 1, ':', ' -> '.join(map(str, s)))


main()
```

> ```
> $ echo 2 144 | python bars.py
> 5 : 2 -> 4 -> 8 -> 16 -> 48 -> 144
> ```